# Android webview is freezing activity while connection type switches

Tags: android, webview, crash

Last days we encountered a strange WebView behavior in android. After the WebView starts loading page and the WebViewClient.onPageStarted event had fired, there was a switch between the connection type in phone at that moment activity was freezed and no error message writen to logcat, last message in logcat where "spin on suspend  threadid". Our activity does not have other threads being executed at that time. We think that it might be an android bug, we did not find a trick to eliminate that behavior.
I get log from logcat, first entry in trace is last log from our app

```
10-02 10:20:43.226: E/timeout(10033): sleep-last our log
10-02 10:20:43.261: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(3150): onReceive() - 
SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED_ACTION
10-02 10:20:43.261: W/SignalStrength(3150): getGsmLevel=4
10-02 10:20:43.261: W/SignalStrength(3150): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 23 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x4)
10-02 10:20:43.261: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(3150): onServiceStateChanged state=0
10-02 10:20:43.261: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(3150): updateDataNetType()
10-02 10:20:43.266: D/TelephonyManager(3322): getLteOnCdmaMode=0 curVal=-1 product_type='' lteOnCdmaProductType=''
10-02 10:20:43.266: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(3150): Nothing, mRoamingIconId = 0
10-02 10:20:43.276: D/STATUSBAR-AirplaneModeQuickSettingButton(3150): mPhoneStateListener - inAirplaneMode: false
10-02 10:20:43.281: W/SignalStrength(3150): getGsmLevel=4
10-02 10:20:43.281: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(3150): onServiceStateChanged state=0
```

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce it again in order to be ready to get more logs? Any webview callback is triggered?

Comment: Yes we reproducing it by switching connection type manually(it is difficult because depends on our human reaction).And trace all our methods step by step and all logs from phone.But we didn't see nothing in logcat. no webview callback